# jQuery not working on live site

Tags: jquery, html

I have the below fiddle which seems to work fine:

```
 jQuery(function() {

     // Remove any double class applications
     jQuery(".pricedisplay .pricedisplay").removeClass("pricedisplay");

     // Load from BitPay's conversion rates JSON page
     jQuery.ajax({
       dataType: "json",
       url: "https://bitpay.com/api/rates",
       success: function(data) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cox6p7br/

However when I try this code live, it's not working.

Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you got jquery reference on your live website??

Comment: Are you linking jQuery on your live page?

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your html file?

Comment: my html looks like this: 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><span class="pricedisplay">10</span></p>
</body>

Comment: thats a no then ^^ lol

Comment: hit f12 and look at your console. What errors do you see? Start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yyou'll want to ensure that you are also properly reference jQuery using a `<script>` tag that either explicitly points to a local file or a CDN that is hosting the library :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
     <!-- Your jQuery Code Here -->
</script>
```

If you are still encountering issues and you are using a local file, then it's likely a problem with how you are referencing the file itself. You can use the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser and take a look at the Console section, which should indicate any issues with loading your file (via a 404 error).

Comment: Thank you so much!! This solved it! Legend!

Comment: One last question, if I wanted to add a percentage to the final value of the BTC on display - how would I go about this?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where you are referring to. If it's the decimal value that appears before "BTC", then you could add it on the line that you set the `text` property via `text: "" + (num / data[member].rate).toFixed(4) + "% BTC*"` as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cox6p7br/2/).

Comment: Sorry what I meant was for example add 10% extra to the value of the BTC

Comment: Ah. Just multiply your calculate by 1.1 : `text: "" + ((num / data[member].rate) * 1.1).toFixed(4) + "% BTC*"`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your time mate

Comment: *"it doesn't currently have a reference to the jQuery library, which you need to add using the External Resources tab on the left"*  ~  This is wrong.  [Click on the gear icon in the "JavaScript" pane and you'll see that jQuery was already properly included in the "Frameworks & Extensions" section](http://jsfiddle.net/cox6p7br/).  So in [your version of the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cox6p7br/1/), jQuery is included twice.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks for that. I generally prefer [JSBin](http://www.jsbin.com) to JSFiddle, so it's been quite a while since I've used it. I'll chalk it up to that.

Comment: I've removed that section of the response as it really wasn't relevant to the actual issue. Thanks again @Sparky